# Spring Boot war deployment with Angular app as static resource

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot backend and an Angular frontend application and can successfully create a runnable jar file from them by simply copying the Angular app into the `resources/static` folder of the Spring Boot app.

Running the jar works fine, i can access the application on `localhost:8000` (since i have the `server.port` property set to `8000`) and it works as intended.

Now i would like to create a deployable **war** file instead of the runnable jar and deploy the app in Tomcat, so i've applied the war plugin and declared the following gradle dependency (as per [this guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-wars)):

```
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

Now the build successfully generates a war file, and Tomcat can deploy and start it without any errors. After the deployment the app is available at `localhost:8080/myapp`

The problem is when i'm actually opening the app, it seemingly tries to fetch the Angular resources from the wrong location and thus resulting in 404 errors:

[image]

As you can see it it tries to fetch the Angular files from `localhost:8080/filename`, but i think it should be `localhost:8080/myapp/filename` (although i'm not sure).

I've tried changing the `server.servlet.context-path` property to `/myapp`, but it has no effect (i guess it would affect only the embedded container).

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to fix it.

First, i had to change the base href of the Angular app in its *index.html* from `/` to `./` as in:

```
<base href="./">
```

After this change the Angular resources did not throw 404 errors anymore, but the backend endpoints still did.

I had the following in my *environments.prod.ts*:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_URL: '/api'
};
```

I'm calling my backend endpoints through this `API_URL`, so i had to change this as well in a similar manner:

```
API_URL: './api'
```

After these changes everything works fine.